# Rails Kaminari from array optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel, kaminari

**Problem:** I have categories and products in categories. Code/queries are very slow.

Each category has subcategories as the same model. Subcategories also have products and maybe subcategories.
So I need to get all products of all subcategories when call parent category.

**category model**

```
  class Category < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
      has_many :categories, as: :parent, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy

      def all_products
        @all_products = []
        all_products_find(self)
        return @all_products
      end

      def all_products_find(category)
        @all_products += category.products
        for cat in category.categories
          all_products_find(cat)
        end
      end
    ...
    end
```

I use Kaminari to paginate array, but before use it, category puts all products to array, so it is very long. How can I paginate_array without gathering all products before?

**my controller's action**

```
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    if !(@category.nil?)
      @products = @category.all_products #still gathering all products -> slow
      @products_part = Kaminari.paginate_array(@products).page(params[:page]).per(12)
    end
```

How can I optimize it?

Comment: Note: Ruby doesn't really use `for`. Instead: `category.categories.each do |cat|` Likewise a `return` at the end of a method is implied. Just do `@all_products` instead of `return @all_products` unless you're explicitly returning from a method early. Your `if !(@category.nil?)` should also be either `if !@category.nil?` or `if (!@category.nil?)` or perhaps `unless @category.nil?` but more honestly it can probably be `if @category` unless there's a chance `@category` can be literal `false`, which I doubt.

Comment: This looks like a class N+1 query situation. Normally you tackle this by having `through:` relationships, or using a `JOIN` in your query to deep fetch everything in one shot.

Comment: I made something like this. I gathered only ids of subcategories and then SELECT products which category_id IN ( @subcategories_ids ).   It is more faster, but I think that there exists more efficient way